# Phusion passenger code being cached?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I was adding some updates to my rails application, as well as upgrading from 3.0.4 to 3.1.1. I then ran into some errors. I was using the request.request_uri method, which threw an error. Once i corrected it locally, i pushed up my code. However even after restarting, the same error is being thrown. I can see my code is corrected on the server. Is there some sort of application caching i should check? Or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a stupid error on my part. Had an app folder sitting under app. So it was picking up the other helper file with the bad code, not the one i had updated. Happy i fixed it at least.